# $X$ follows normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

$X$ follows normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$. Find distribution of $X^2$. My question is why we are allowed to calculate this as follows:

\begin{align*}P\left(-\sqrt t \le X\le \sqrt t\right) &=F_X(\sqrt{t})-F_X(-\sqrt{t})\\
&=\frac{\partial F_X(\sqrt{t})}{\partial t} - \frac{F_X(-\sqrt{t})}{\partial t}\\
&=f_x(\sqrt{t})(\sqrt{t})^\prime-f_x(\sqrt{t})^\prime(\sqrt{t})\end{align*}

I mean how is it possible that we have derivatives here? Why to apply this strange formula for derivatives at the end (it does not seem to be a normal product rule).

Comment: There is no lowercase $x$ in this problem, and the second equality is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a product rule but a chain rule. You have $(F_X)'(t) = f_x(t)$ so $$(F_X(\sqrt{t}))' = F_X'(\sqrt{t}) (\sqrt{t})' = \frac{f_x(\sqrt{t})}{2\sqrt{t}}. $$

Comment: This is not quite correct. There is an additional factor of $2$ because of the map $x \mapsto x^2$ being two-to-one. The way the OP wrote it, this factor comes out because $F_{X^2}(t)=F_X(\sqrt{t})-F_X(-\sqrt{t})$.

Comment: understand, second part of my question was why do we use those derivatives?

Comment: @mkropkowski The derivative of the cumulative distribution function (CDF) is the probability density function (PDF). We usually like to describe the distribution of a continuous random variable in terms of its PDF.

Comment: The distribution of a normal variable is given in terms of the probability density function which is the derivative of the cumulative distribution function. $X$ doesn't have a "nice" (elementary) cumulative distribution function and so you can't expect $X^2$ to have one so you should find the density function instead.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking "why is there a derivative". Well, what if I had some function $F(u)$ and I told you to take the derivative. you might say,
$$f(u)\cdot u'$$
right? It's the same concept. As for the approach, it is equivalent to using a "regular" change of variable
$$f_Y(y) = \frac{f_X(\sqrt y)}{\left|\frac{dy}{dx}\right|}+\frac{f_X(-\sqrt y)}{\left|\frac{dy}{dx}\right|}= f_X(\sqrt y)\left|\frac{dx}{dy}\right|+f_X(-\sqrt y)\left|\frac{dx}{dy}\right|$$